# Why is change detection not triggering on nested dynamic component

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, angular-content-projection

I have an issue with change detection on nested dynamic component using content projection.
Change detection is not triggering automatically on the child component, I have to add manual change detection to every actions.

An exemple here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k2z661?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

As you can see, if you click the button, nothing is showing, but when adding the `this.cdr.detectChanges()` line on the add() function, the content is showing.
Also, you can notice that I'm not using
`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Is there a way to achieve that without adding the manual change detection everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found what was going on. The child view need to be manually attached to the appref. So

```
private appRef: ApplicationRef
```

need to be added to the constructor and then, attach the child view:

```
    this.appRef.attachView(refChild.hostView);
```

I've updated the Stackblitz.